# NSPasteboard generalPasteboard returns nil

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, appkit, nspasteboard

I'm attempting to copy an `NSString` to the pasteboard from within an `NSBundle` that is loaded inside another program as a plugin.

For some reason, `[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard]` is returning nil.

My code is from Apple's [NSPasteboard documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nspasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSPasteboard programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Articles/pbCopying.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008102-SW1):

```
NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];

// Outputs: (null)
NSLog(@"%@", pasteboard);

[pasteboard clearContents];
BOOL copiedToPasteboard = [pasteboard writeObjects:@[@"The string"]];
```

Is there something I could have inadvertently done to cause this?

Comment: @samfisher yes my question is about `Cocoa`.

Comment: Are you using ARC? It might be a compiler bug...

Comment: @H2CO3 not using ARC. If I was, how would I prove that it is a compiler bug?

Comment: @MichaelRobinson: By assigning to an instance variable or something instead and showing that the memory management is inconsistent. Anyway, though, are you doing anything odd? Is this a normal Cocoa app just like you'd get from a "Cocoa (Document-Based/CoreData/Whatever) Application" template, or are there any "twists" to it? For example, if this is a command-line app or uses a compatibility UI toolkit, that's relevant.

Comment: It is an `NSBundle` that is loaded as a plugin inside the main App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved by reinstalling my OS.

I can only assume that something, somewhere, at some time became corrupted, causing this infuriating issue.

Comment: You answer would not have compiled.

Answer (score 1):

I have built a minimal app that loads a bundle and added logging of the value returned by `[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard]` at each step. Unfortunately, I was not able to reproduce this issue. Here is the output that I get:

```
NUAppDelegate> init:<NSPasteboard: 0x100647740>
NUAppDelegate> awakeFromNib:<NSPasteboard: 0x100647740>
NUAppDelegate> applicationDidFinishLaunching::<NSPasteboard: 0x100647740>
Loading plugin
Plugin> init:<NSPasteboard: 0x100647740>
Plugin> someMethod:<NSPasteboard: 0x100647740>
```

Without more details I don't see how we can find an answer. Do you have some code we can download or inspect?

Comment: I've done this as well. My issue is difficult to debug, as my project is an `NSBundle` that is loaded as a plugin inside an application I have no control over (or the source code). My testers do not have the same broken behaviour, so I am starting to think that this issue is localized to my machine only.